# Cucumber JVM Junit Runner cucumber api does not exist

Tags: java, junit, jvm, cucumber, appium

I use  cucumber JVM with mobile automation tests and it works fine but I need to run to my runner classes from command line  for build server. When I use the

```
javac -cp .;C:\V3\YemeksepetiAndroid.v3.Tests\AndroidV3\src\test\java\com\cucumber\AndroidV3\junit-4.11.jar Galaxy_S4_Runner.java
```

for run as you can see the screenshot (http://prntscr.com/9mrr1i
) it gives error. Anyone help me ? :)

This is my runner class

```
package com.cucumber.AndroidV3;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@CucumberOptions(

format = { "pretty", "html:target/html/s4/" },

features = { "src/test/resource" }, tags = { "@s4" }

)

public class Galaxy_S4_Runner {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the two Cucumber jars (cucumber-java.jar and cucumber-core.jar) on your classpath along with junit-4.11.jar. You should be able to find them in a Maven repository.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I already have cucumber jars  (cucumber-java.jar and cucumber-core.jar) . I really dont understant why cannot find it http://prntscr.com/9mtipf

Comment: That's the classpath from Maven, not the classpath on the command line. `java -cp ... ` needs to mention the two cucumber jars, and any other dependent jars.

Comment: To be honest, you'd be better off running those tests on your build server through maven.